# Time Complexity of Differentiating Priority Queue Heap Via Key

Tags: java, heap, binary-tree, scheduling, priority-queue

I have a priority queue max heap where each element is a class called Task, which looks as follows (implemented in Java, but question is language-agnostic):

```
class Task{

    int ID
    int Priority
    int Time

    public Task(int i, int p, int t){
        this.ID = i;
        this.Priority = p;
        this.Time = t;
    }

    //Getters, etc
}
```

The heap is obviously sorted by priority. The operation I want to perform is to find the highest priority item, decrement its Time value, and remove it from the heap if the time score changes to 0. HOWEVER, here's the catch: there is allowed to be more than one Task with the same Priority. In this case, I compare the ID scores of all such Tasks and operate on the lowest one.

What would be the worst case running time of such an operation? If every element has the same Priority, I would end up searching through the entire tree, meaning that this couldn't possibly be done in less than O(n) time, correct? This seems impossible to get around because the IDs are unsorted. However, I'm told that this is possible to do in O(log n), which I don't understand at all. Would anyone be able to clarify where I'm approaching this wrong?

Comment: the tags you've chosen don't have many followers, I suggest you use a language tag even if the question is language agnostic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `java.util.PriorityQueue` (of `Task` instances) [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#PriorityQueue-java.util.Comparator-) can take a `Comparator` that can take into account the `Task#Priority` and `Task#ID` which means that the (priority) ties could be broken based on ID's which are (supposedly) unique. So, a Task `t1(Priority=5, ID=100, Time=10)` could precede (i.e. be prioritized over) a Task `t2(Priority=5, ID=110, Time=10)`.

Removing such an item (which is at the root) that has highest priority along with others that may have the same priority, zero Time remaining **and** lowest ID is still an `O(log(n))` operation in a heap or priority queue while maintaining the heap property. Note that priority queues are not great for *searching* (hash tables or binary search trees do that well); but for inserting or removing while maintaining the heap property. You should just work with the [`peek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#peek--) and [`remove`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html#remove--) API methods to achieve the operation you need while ensuring the time complexity (`O(log n)`) that the priority queue is designed for.

Comment: I should clarify that I haven't used PriorityQueue, I'm storing the heap in an array. But your answer has given me the idea that I could do add an additional condition to my Insert which pushes the lower ID up the heap if the Priorities are the same. Then the operation I described above would just have to be done to the root every time. Not a direct answer, but you got me thinking in the right direction, so thanks!

Comment: In the sense that I'm not using the PriorityQueue utility, I've created the implementation from scratch. I am aware that PriorityQueue uses an array as well, that could have been worded better.